# Removing Junk Software/Partition That Comes On USB Stick

Tags: partitioning, usb-storage, boot-partition

Okay so I bought a EMTEC 8GB thumb drive today to load a LIVE bodhi(ubuntu) on in order to repair my system.

Right now, I am currently booted on a debian live CD (Elive)

I'm trying to install Bodhi on my system, but there seems to be pre-installed software on the USB. This software is for windows and it is for locking/unlocking your drive with a password. Problem is, it auto-mounts and it is also stopping my USB from being bootable...

The software on the drive is called LOCKv100 and the pdf provided is next to useless

I've tried using dd to write 0s to everything and I've also tried gparted and unetbootin... Here is what I'm dealing with.

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 8006 MB, 8006926336 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 973 cylinders, total 15638528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ce617

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63    15631244     7815591    b  W95 FAT32
```

**df -h**....

```
/dev/sr1        2.6M  2.6M     0 100% /media/光碟機
```

really annoying

**lsblk....**

```
sdc      8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   7.5G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1     4M  0 rom  /media/光碟機
```

So there are the details on the drive. /dev/sr1 is the virtual CD with the software that it auto-mounts every time I plug it in. This is a 'read-only file system' so I am having troubles getting rid of it and it is invisible in gparted, as well as fdisk.

I can easily wipe /dev/sdc1. which is the main partition of the USB stick

Does anyone know of any way to get rid of EVERYTHING on this drive and just make it a standard, single partition drive.

I have literally googled for a few hours now and a lot of the solutions are for Windows only, which is not an option for me. I've heard the HP USB Format tool works wonders for this, but it's only for windows.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: If this is a U3 drive, the process to disable the U3 features is extensive, so much so the tools might not even be available since it was depreciated by 99% of the vendors years ago.

Comment: No, not U3. Yeah I read a bunch of stuff on that.

Comment: It's called LOCKv100 sorry, editing post now

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Try GParted and just format the disk?